# apply WebServices into VSTS on modified field

Tags: azure-devops

I have a question regarding VSTS,

Let's assume that I have a requirement which says when a user modifies a field in WorkItem then automatically should update an other field in external database.

I do not have experience at all with VSTS and is not clear to me yet how I can do this. 
Already I created  webservices in order to write to the field in the external database and then the big question is how to call this webservices each time that a field is modified.

Does someone have a suggestion or an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is using VSTS web hook:

1. Go to service hooks page (`https://[account].visualstudio.com/[team project]/_apps/hub/ms.vss-servicehooks-web.manageServiceHooks-project`)
2. Click + > Select Web Hooks > Select Work Item updated event > Specify Field and other filters > Next
3. Specify your web services URL and other settings (the web services need to be accessible from internet)

After that, when the specified work item updated and meet other filters (specified in web hook), it will send the request to target service with json data.

Comment: until now i found this nuget package but did not find example how to used it. 
could you please provide more info?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.VSTS/1.2.1

Comment: @NikosKou With VSTS web hook, you don't need to do something extra with your web services, just create a web hook in your VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you are talking about VSTS (Cloud) not TFS (On-premises), the only option to create extension which listen to work-item update once it happen, it will call your web service

I created series of videos on how to develop VSTS extension, how to publish it and you can see it as a starting point.

http://mohamedradwan.com/2017/12/29/develop-vsts-extension-and-configure-ci-continuous-integration-and-cd-continuous-delivery-pipeline/